# Cannot result R.string.page_title, R.string.page_title, R.layout.main etc

Tags: android

I am new to Java and Android development. I am using Android Studio and learning how to parse XML data from this guide: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml#analyze

I created a new class `Network Activity` and put all the code from the guide there.

The code from the website uses:

- R.string.page_title
- R.string.page_title
- R.string.connection_error
- R.string.xml_error
- R.layout.main
- R.id.webview

Every single one of them throws `cannot find symbol variable X` error.

I tried:

1. Closing and opening Android Studio and/or cleaning and rebuilding
2. I added `Network Activity` to `AndroidManifext.xml`
3. I made sure I don't `import android.R`.

I followed every solution I could find online and I still have this problem.

Comment: have you declared those strings in strings.xml?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sample code from this guide uses these strings, for example when returning an error :

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
    try {
        return loadXmlFromNetwork(urls[0]);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return getResources().getString(R.string.connection_error);
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        return getResources().getString(R.string.xml_error);
    }
}
```

You need to add these values to your `strings.xml` file. It should be located under `res/values/strings.xml` and will look like this after you add the necessary values :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">YourApp</string>
    <string name="page_title">A title</string>
    <string name="connection_error">Error text</string>
    ...
</resources>
```

Comment: Well... I guess I skipped a few lessons. What about `R.layout` and `R.id`, where should they be placed?

Comment: Your main layout file should be located under `res/layout/main.xml`. This file must contain a `WebView` widget with the id `webview`.